# Using result of one query in another query : nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to count the number of documents in a collection and then use the result into another insert query using Node.js.

```js
var number;
db.collection("collection").countDocuments({}, function(error, numOfDocs){
    if(error) throw error;
    else{
        console.log(numOfDocs);
        number = numOfDocs;
    }
}); 

var myobj = { num: "Number_"+number };
db.collection("another_collection").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) 
{
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document inserted");         
});
```

The inserted value in the collection is `{ "num" : "Number_undefined" }`

How to use the result of the first query into another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have not given `Number` a value. Further, the `count()` function is a async function (I wrote an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268715/why-asynchronous-over-synchronous-functions/52269244#52269244) about that). Try this:

```
db.collection('collection')
  .countDocuments({}, function(error, numOfDocs){
    if(error) throw error;
    else {
        var myobj = { num: 'Number_' + numOfDocs };
        db.collection('another_collection').insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
               if (err) throw err;
               console.log('1 document inserted');         
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @weirdpanda. But this generates an error "MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed". Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It's not because of this code. Are you using `db.close()` somewhere after this bit?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was using db.close()
Removed that and it works fine now.